# convert .mdf file to .sql script (mac)

Tags: mysql, sql, converters

I have .mdf file (MS SQL backup) and i want to convert it to .sql. So I dont want to use MS anymore but Mysql.
Is there a way to convert the .mdf file to sql? Perfect would be if it also recreates the relations etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

mdf is the binary file of a database.  The tool that allows you to access the data in a mdf file is SQL Server.  There are no other tools to work with these files -- there are many tools which allow you to export the data and structure of a SQL Server database and they are all included in the SQL Server product.  In the UI you can select "script database".  There are also ways to export tables.